# How to receive child_process from python, and execute javascript code at the same time?

Tags: javascript, python, child-process, yolov5

I am trying to write a js call yolo in python to complete the detection of people and return the coordinates of the person to js, and then move the camera

```
const yoloProcess = spawn(
  "C:\\Users\\LAB908\\anaconda3\\envs\\yolov5\\python",
  [
    "C:\\Users\\LAB908\\Downloads\\yolov5-deepsparse-blogpost-main\\yolov5-train\\detect.py",
    "--class",
    "0",
    "--weights",
    "yolov5s.pt",
    "--source",
    "rtsp://admin:123456@169.254.10.100/stream0",
  ],
  {
    encoding: "utf8",
  }
);
```

```
var i = 1;
yoloProcess.stderr.on("data", async (data) => {
  left = data.toString().split(",")[0].replace("(", "");
  right = data.toString().replace(")", "").replace("\n", "").split(",")[1];
  //console.log(data.toString());

  console.log("left:" + String(left));
  console.log("right:" + String(right));

  await sleep(3000);
  pos.push((parseFloat(right) + parseFloat(left)) / 2);

  console.log(pos);

  if (pos[i] - pos[i - 1] > 0) {
    await move_right();
    console.log("move right");
  } else if (pos[i] - pos[i - 1] < 0) {
    await move_left();
    console.log("move left");
  } else {
    await move_stop();
    console.log("do not move");
  }
});
```

But process still receiving all the time, without moving the camera function and sleeping. I don't know what's wrong?
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiPKk.png)

Comment: you can't do this `i[i - 1]` if variable i is an Integer.

Comment: Are you trying to write `pos[i-1]` instead of `i[i - 1]`?

Comment: Yes! sorry I wrote wrong , but the result is still the same